# How to stop base static events/actions firing in other derived classes

Tags: c#, events

I am working on an LOB application in C# using a WinForms tabbed MDI interface. I have various forms with DataGridViews to allow the user to select an object they are interested in, which they can then view/edit in a new form.

Each of my main business objects inherit from Entity, which is defined as below:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public static event Action Saved;

    internal virtual void OnSaved()
    {
        if (Saved != null)
        {
            Saved();
        }
    }
}
```

I then have the objects that populate the grid (these are actually auto-generated classes from Linq-to-SQL, although I can replicate the problem with normal classes):

```
class Class1 : Entity
{
    //Stuff
}


class Class2 : Entity
{
    //Stuff
}
```

I want to know when an object of a given class is modified, but i don't care which instance (hence the static action) so that i can refresh the grid and perform other activities.

The problem comes when the event is fired from a derived class instance - it fires for all other derived classes too. For example:

```
Class1.Saved += new Action(s1);
Class2.Saved += new Action(s2);

private void TestIt()
{
    Class2 o2 = new Class2();
    o2.OnSaved();  
}
```

This would fire s1 and s2, but I only want the specific one to be fired (i.e. s2). What is the best way to do this? I have quite a few classes that need this behviour and would like to avoid having to add any code to each class if possible.

### Update:

Thank you for all your responses, they have been very helpful.

I have opted for a slightly different option, which I admit seems quite hacky, but works well for my purposes. This involves passing the type with the action and letting a handler filter and call relevant operations.

Entity Class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public static event Action<Type> Saved;


    internal void OnSaved()
    {
        private Action<Type> SavedCopy = Saved;        

        if (SavedCopy != null)
            SavedCopy(this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Hook up handler:

```
 Entity.Saved += new Action<Type>(Handler);
```

Example Handler method (this will vary from form to form):

```
    void Handler(Type obj)
    {
       if (obj==typeof(Class1))
           UpdateGrid();
       else if (obj==typeof(Class2))
           UpdateBasicInfo();
       else if (obj == typeof(Class3))
           DoAnotherThing();
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is that `Class1.Saved` is just another way to write `Entity.Saved`, there's just one event, not one per class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure doing it like this is a good idea, but you could specify the type when you subscribe and when you save the data:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Action> Subscribers
         = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();

    internal virtual void OnSaved()
    {
        OnSaved(GetType());
    }

    private OnSaved(Type type)
    {
        Action subscribed;
        Subscribers.TryGetValue(type, out subscribed);
        if (subscribed != null)
            subscribed();
    }

    public Subscribe(Type type, Action action)
    {
        Action subscribed;
        Subscribers.TryGetValue(type, out subscribed);
        Subscribers[type] = subscribed + action;
    }

    public Unsubscribe(Type type, Action action)
    {
        Action subscribed;
        Subscribers.TryGetValue(type, out subscribed);
        Subscribers[type] = subscribed - action;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this code is not thread-safe, so if you want to use it from different threads at the same time, you need to add locking.

Comment: I've selected this as the answer as it gave me the idea of passing the type and filtering

Answer (score 1):

Using generics could be a work around; each generic class gets a copy of the static fields.

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    public static event Action Saved = delegate { };

    internal virtual void OnSaved()
    {
        Saved();
    }
}

class Class1 : Entity<Class1>
{
    //Stuff
}

class Class2 : Entity<Class2>
{
    //Stuff
}
```

Comment: This is something I had considered as I am already using generics in the way you describe. In fact my classes inherit EntityT<T> which itself inherits Entity. My problem with this was due to the way i am raising the event. I am overriding LinqToSQl SubmitChanges() and casting the ChangeSet Inserts, Updates and Deletes to Entity and raising the event for each, I'm not sure how this works if I don't have a non generic base class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an event per type, because can't determine for which type the delegate is registered when the event is defined on the base type.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    internal abstract void OnSaved();
}

class Class1 : Entity
{
    public static event Action Saved = () => { };

    internal override void OnSaved()
    {
        this.Saved();
    }

    //Stuff
}

class Class2 : Entity
{
    public static event Action Saved = () => { };

    internal override void OnSaved()
    {
        this.Saved();
    }

    //Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be static?  Make it an instance event instead.

```
public event Action Saved;
```

You have to hook it up for each instance instead of just once per class (or, in your current case, once), but it will separate the events.